# insert and convert null to 0

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Ive got table with null values in it. I would like to copy this table to another and replace null value from one column to for example 0. Is it possible cause my target table doesnt accept null values in this colum

`Insert into MyNewTable (A, B, C) select (AA, BB, CC) from MyOldTable`

And CC may be null

thanks for any help

Comment: Bye? You're leaving so soon? What about our comments/answers?

Comment: @BoltClock - having fun just at the start of weekend... haha..:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `ISNULL()`

```
Insert into MyNewTable (A, B, C) select (AA, BB, ISNULL(CC,0)) from MyOldTable
```

Comment: Wrong. (AA,BB,CC) is a triplet that is not recognized by SQL Server

Answer (score 5):

You can use both `IsNull(a, b)` or `Coalesce(a, b, c, ...)` functions, where IsNull returns the value of "b" if "a" is null, and Coalesce returns the first non-null argument.
An important difference is that IsNull() forces the casting (or convert) of "b" to the type of "a", while Coalesce's return type is the same of the returned argument, letting the engine to try any conversion only AFTER the evaluation of the function.

I.e. if the column "a" is of `int` data type, writing `IsNull(a, '1')` is ok, but `IsNull(a, 'hello')` causes a conversion error, while writing `Coalesce(a, 'hello')` is allowed, and an error will be raised only if `a` is null and you try, for example, to insert the returned value ('hello') to an `int` column, but doing auotmatic conversion of `a`'s value (if not null) when inserting in a varchar column.

Comment: Brilliant, was just going to look up the difference between these two but you saved me the trouble.

Comment: @Stuart: always happy to help. Thank you for grammar corrections. I know my english is not very good.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `coalesce` function for this:

```
INSERT INTO MyNewTable (A, B, C)
SELECT COALESCE(AA, 0), COALESCE(BB, 0), COALESCE(CC, 0) FROM MyOldTable
```